# Servidor FTP, me pide contraseña aunque tenga la autentificacion anonima

Tags: windows, ftp

Estoy creando un servidor ftp en Windows 10 para que compartir imágenes de y datos de un sistema de vision artificial, el problema es que aún cuando solo dejo la autentificacion anónima, me sigue requiriendo usuario y contraseña, ingreso la contraseña y usuario del administrador, y me niega el acceso por datos incorrectos.
Ayudaaaaa